# Как на гистограмме chart js при на ведении на элемент вывести несколько значений?

Tags: диаграммы

Мне нужно отобразить на гистограмме несколько значений при наведении на элемент.
Вот скрин: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        var HealthChartContainer = document.getElementById('HealthChart');
        var HealthChart = HealthChartContainer.getContext('2d');

        var dataset = {
            labels: [
                    @for(var i=0;i<Model.data.Count-1; i++){
                        @:'@(Model.data[i].Item1)',
                    }
                '@(Model.data[Model.data.Count-1].Item1)'
            ],

            datasets: [{
                label: '@Model.vAxisTitle',
                data: [@(string.Join(", ", Model.data.Select(s => s.Item2.ToString())))
                ],
                backgroundColor: 'blue',
              
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: '#777',
                hoverBorderWidth: 3,
                hoverBorderColor: '#000'
            }]
        };

            const config = {
            type: 'bar',
                data: dataset,
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                legend: {
                    display: false
                },
                title: {
                    display: false,
                    text: 'Chart.js Bar Chart'
                },
                scales: {
                    y: {
                        ticks: {
                            callback: function (value) {return Number.isInteger(value) ? value : '';}
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
        };

        var Chart = new Chart(HealthChart, config);
        </script>
```

Comment: Мою проблему помогло решеить это видео: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UxJ5d-HGhJA

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант 1**

Согласно документации на тултип можно воздействовать через опции создав соответсвующие [калбэки](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-callbacks)

```
options: {
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        callbacks: {
          footer(e){
            return 'Данные столбца:' + e[0].dataset.data[e[0].dataIndex]
          } ,
        }
      }
    },
}
```

Данный пример добавляет футер к тултипу выделенного столбца

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таким же образом можно преобразовывать остальные выводимые данные, в том числе label и т.п.

**Вариант 2**

Если этих возможностей будет не достаточно то вот код, созданный на основе [исходников(docs)](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/docs/samples/tooltip/html.md) в котором можно полностью кастомизировать тултип:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <title></title>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.0/chart.min.js" integrity="sha512-TW5s0IT/IppJtu76UbysrBH9Hy/5X41OTAbQuffZFU6lQ1rdcLHzpU5BzVvr/YFykoiMYZVWlr/PX1mDcfM9Qg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
   <style> 
        #tooltip {
            opacity: 0;
            position: absolute;
        }
    </style> 
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="chart"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var ctx = document.getElementById('chart'); 
  const tooltip = document.getElementById("tooltip");
  const getOrCreateTooltip = (chart) => {
    let tooltipEl = chart.canvas.parentNode.querySelector('#tooltip');

    if (!tooltipEl) {
      tooltipEl = document.createElement('div');
      tooltipEl.id = 'tooltip';
      tooltipEl.style.background = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)';
      tooltipEl.style.borderRadius = '3px';
      tooltipEl.style.color = 'white';
      tooltipEl.style.opacity = 1;
      tooltipEl.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
      tooltipEl.style.position = 'absolute';
      tooltipEl.style.transform = 'translate(-50%, 0)';
      tooltipEl.style.transition = 'all .1s ease';

      const table = document.createElement('table');
      table.style.margin = '0px';

      tooltipEl.appendChild(table);
      chart.canvas.parentNode.appendChild(tooltipEl);
    }

    return tooltipEl;
  };

const externalTooltipHandler = (context) => {
  // Tooltip Element
  const {chart, tooltip} = context;
  const tooltipEl = getOrCreateTooltip(chart);

  // Hide if no tooltip
  if (tooltip.opacity === 0) {
    tooltipEl.style.opacity = 0;
    return;
  }

  // Set Text
  if (tooltip.body) {
    const titleLines = tooltip.title || [];
    const bodyLines = tooltip.body.map(b => b.lines);

    const tableHead = document.createElement('thead');

    titleLines.forEach(title => {
      const tr = document.createElement('tr');
      tr.style.borderWidth = 0;

      const th = document.createElement('th');
      th.style.borderWidth = 0;
      const text = document.createTextNode(title);

      th.appendChild(text);
      tr.appendChild(th);
      tableHead.appendChild(tr);
    });

    const tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');
    bodyLines.forEach((body, i) => {
      const colors = tooltip.labelColors[i];

      const span = document.createElement('span');
      span.style.background = colors.backgroundColor;
      span.style.borderColor = colors.borderColor;
      span.style.borderWidth = '2px';
      span.style.marginRight = '10px';
      span.style.height = '10px';
      span.style.width = '10px';
      span.style.display = 'inline-block';

      const tr = document.createElement('tr');
      tr.style.backgroundColor = 'inherit';
      tr.style.borderWidth = 0;

      const td = document.createElement('td');
      td.style.borderWidth = 0;

      const text = document.createTextNode(body);

      td.appendChild(span);
      td.appendChild(text);
      tr.appendChild(td);
      tableBody.appendChild(tr);
    });

    const tableRoot = tooltipEl.querySelector('table');

    // Remove old children
    while (tableRoot.firstChild) {
      tableRoot.firstChild.remove();
    }

    // Add new children
    tableRoot.appendChild(tableHead);
    tableRoot.appendChild(tableBody);
  }

  const {offsetLeft: positionX, offsetTop: positionY} = chart.canvas;

  // Display, position, and set styles for font
  tooltipEl.style.opacity = 1;
  tooltipEl.style.left = positionX + tooltip.caretX + 'px';
  tooltipEl.style.top = positionY + tooltip.caretY + 'px';
  tooltipEl.style.font = tooltip.options.bodyFont.string;
  tooltipEl.style.padding = tooltip.options.padding + 'px ' + tooltip.options.padding + 'px';
};

    new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{

            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            tooltip: {
              callbacks:{
                title(e){
                  console.log(e)
                }
              }, 
            },
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        plugins: {
          tooltip: {
            enabled: false,
            external: externalTooltipHandler,
          }
        },
      }
    });
</script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

`externalTooltipHandler` - функция которая будет отрабатывать перед отображением, поэтому там можно добавить любую соответствующую информацию.